# how to add 2-item array inside React dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have an array as follows:
[image]

I want to add the above array of timestamps inside a dropdown using React dropdown,
I have done as follows:

```
 let new_arr = [];
for (let i = start_ts; i < end_ts; i = i + interval) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  console.log('arr', arr);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    new_arr.push(arr.slice(i, i + 2));
  }
  const defaultoption = new_arr[0];
return (
    <View style={width > 414 ? styles.container_web : styles.container_mob}>
      <View style={styles.inner_container}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image source={Images.back_icon} style={{height: 15, width: 15}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Dropdown options={new_arr} value={defaultoption} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

which resulted it to look as follows:
[image]
[image]

However I want the dropdown to look as follows:
[image]

Any idea or suggestion how should I do it? Any help would be great.
Thank you

Comment: can you add more information, what's `Dropdown`? are you using a 3rd party library of a Dropdown component?

Comment: Are you looking something like this:

Code : `${new Date(1602700200).toDateString()} - ${new Date(1627900200).toDateString()}`

Result: "Mon Jan 19 1970 - Tue Jan 20 1970"

Comment: yes @KirankumarAmbati

Comment: @KirankumarAmbati could you please write a snippet that relates to my code with your logic please? It would be a great help

Comment: yes, am using React-Dropdown as a package from npm @zb22

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Modify the values as per your code:

```js
    let arr = [];
    let new_arr = [];
    let start_ts = 1602700200;
    let end_ts = 1602900200;
    for (let i = start_ts; i < end_ts; i = i + 100000) {
        const date = new Date(i);
        arr.push(`${date.getDate()} ${date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' }).slice(0, 3)}`);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        new_arr.push(arr.slice(i, i + 2).join(' - '));
      }
      console.log('newarr', new_arr);
```

[image: result_image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to produce the date from timestamp.

```
const timestamp = 1605680190229;
const date = new Date(timestamp);

console.log(`${date.getDate()} ${date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' }).slice(0, 3)}`); // "18 Nov"
```

From here, I think you can do the rest. I see you already know how to use Dropdown.